# MySQL - How to combine tables from two databases into one php query string with $_GET?

Tags: php, mysql, database, get

I want to query multiple tables data from two databases and display the data in a unique id php query string. e.g `?player=123456789`. 
Both databases have a table that is storing a unique ID that will be used to show a players data. The ID tables between the databases cannot match eachother in any way. I want to mention that I know how to do this with one database at the time.

For example I have `steamID` for `$db1` players and a `playerID` for `$db2` players. 
There is no unique similarity between the IDs from each database. 
I am using `intval($_GET['player'])` to display data in the php query string.
`$db1` works fine if queried alone, so does `$db2` but how can I combine the both to show in my query string? My code down below.

```
$db1 = 'SELECT * FROM `wm_round_stats` WHERE `steam_id_64`= '.intval($_GET['player']);
$db2 = "SELECT map, COUNT(killerId) AS totalkills
FROM hlstats_Events_Frags 
WHERE killerId='" intval($_GET['player']) "' GROUP BY map ORDER BY map";
```

`WHERE killerId='" intval($_GET['player']) "'`  `WHERE steam_id_64='" intval($_GET['player'])`

How to combine these two above and both databases?

`steamID` is `steam_id_64` and `playerID` is `killerId` in my code from my example above.

I am grateful for the help!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. I assume you want to use one query to get your results? You can do that if the two databases can "see" each other (e.g. same server, federated tables, ...), you can then e.g. use `select * from db1.wm_round_stats rs join db2.hlstats_Events_Frags ef on rs.steam_id_64 = ef.killerId`. How exactly you want to combine them depends on the expected result.